# Add a buzzer to a low current LED

Tags: led, circuit-design

The attached circuit works fine. The LED turns ON when SENSE PROBE and GROUND PROBE are NOT attached. The circuit is fed by a 5V battery. Somehow, the LED is not bright enough to begin with, but I could live with that. Now I am trying to add a small buzzer that also goes off whenever the LED is ON.

Adding that buzzer directly with the LED does not work. I measured the voltage across the LED and it was about 1.84V. That is not enough to trigger the buzzer. Connecting the buzzer to 5V and ground works fine. Is there a way to add a low current relay so that it turns ON the buzzer with the LED?[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

HFE reduces towards 10% when saturated , so R4 needs to. Be reduced to 10% or less with the buzzer on, maybe a bit less than 10%. Then both buzzer and LED should work. But buzzer would be louder between collector and V+.  Try 1k.

I assume you are using a polarized buzzer and maybe the polarity is wrong.

Most common are magnetic 30 mA buzzers or 167 Ohms @ 5V. My analysis indicates about 158 Ohms confirms my experience.  Therefore for full bright Green and buzzer loudness, **choose R4 = near 860 Ohms and check polarity**

[image]

Comment: I actually tried that. I even tried it without any resistor, but no sound from the buzzer

Comment: LM339 is an open collector comparator that shuts off LED. You need the resistor to turn it on.  Report R, Vb and Vc under all test condtions with/out buzzer on Q1

Comment: Did you have the buzzer on the correct polarity? or type?

Comment: Looks like a 30 mA buzzer but only drawing 12 mA so to get 50mA= 20mA LED + 30mA buzzer = 50 mA so drive base pullup with 5mA or 4.3V/ 5mA = just under 1k.. so if it didn't buzz then you have the polarity wrong or wrong type.

Comment: The blue worked great. Thank you

Comment: Blue was the problem. Red was the solution (hmm)

Comment: My bad, red is the solution

Answer (score 2):

Try making R4 smaller and wire the buzzer as shown: -

[image]

If this doesn't work, I'd be tempted to use a logic-level driven MOSFET instead of a BJT for Q1.

Comment: how much buzz would you expect to lose with R4= 2.2K on  150 ohm buzzer with a 2N3904 in dB?

Comment: If the buzzer was 150 ohm then I would want R4 to be more like 1k2. 1k2 draws around 3.6 mA into the base and, given a hFE of ten when saturating, it would be able to supply the 33.3 mA of the buzzer @TonyStewartSunnyskyguyEE75 and, you have my permission to hi-jack my amended diagram LOL.

Comment: You ought to analyze his test results as I did , instead of guessing

Comment: I didn’t find any test results in the question and I don’t see any now.

Comment: not much , but enough ... " voltage across the LED and it was about 1.84V"